# Как нормализовать координаты для обучения YOLO

Tags: координаты, преобразование

У меня есть набор изображений аннотированный ограничивающими рамками в формате x0, y0, x1, y1
Как перевести эти координаты в формат x, y, w, h с нормализованными значениями от 0 до 1

**Пример формата моих координат:**[574.0, 2586.0, 575.0, 2635.0]
**Пример формата который требуется:** [0.028524857375713107, 0.21801143730810751, 0.057049714751426214, 0.048084704845887456]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разделить на соответствующие размеры экрана или чего у вас там?